# In FoxPro, why is selected table changing within form if form called from a button in a grid?

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a master form that calls a form called freight.
This freight form has all properties set to default except Caption, Name and window type which is 1-Modal.
The only method with code is the init which has:

```
select FRT1
```

The only object on the form is a command button with this in the click method:

```
messagebox(alias())
thisform.release()
```

So I would expect when I press the command button, the messagebox would say [FRT1] but instead it gives another alias from the master form.

Before the form is called from the master form, the alias is also explicitly set to FRT1

```
select FRT1
do form freight
```

Because the Freight form is modal, I would expect nothing in the master form to affect the data areas while the Freight form is running.

Since there is practically nothing in the Freight form, the problem would seem to be in the master form.

This errant behavior seems to only occur if the freight form is called from a button within a grid.   Any ideas on what is happening or how to prevent it?

Comment: As Cetin said, Vfp's `Grid` control is able to change the current work-area when it gets the focus. I'd also suggest to use private data-sessions, and write code that as far as possible does not rely on the current alias() by using the `IN` clauses of commands and the alias parameters of functions that have one, e.g. `Replace ... In myAlias` , `Skip In myAlias`, `Seek(someValue, "myAlias", "myTagName")`and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few thoughts.

I would open your debugger and put a

```
SET STEP ON
```

immediately before doing the

```
SELECT FRT1
DO FORM FREIGHT
```

Then, in the debugger, go to the "Watch" window and enter the value

```
ALIAS()
```

as the value to watch and to a click in the left-bar to show the red dot to STOP when it changes.

Just a thought of expectation.  Your "Freight" form has its "DataSession" property to "1-Default data session", and if so, it is looking at whatever alias is in the DEFAULT session and not a PRIVATE data session that your master form may have...

I have seen this only EXTREMELY RARE cases ( 2 times ever in the 25+ yrs of working with FoxBase, FoxPro, VFP).  In these cases, I had to EXPLICITLY do a select of the table TWICE in a row.

```
SELECT FRT1
SELECT FRT1
```

or even putting a bogus statement in between such as

```
SELECT FRT1
tmpXXXXXX = alias()
SELECT FRT1
```

Check with breakpoint and see if that works.

Only one other breakpoint I would TRY to do... put "PROGRAM()" in the watch window. Is it possibly calling some other derived class script you did not know about... or in the "DataEnvironment" of the form running code such as in the "BeforeOpenTables" event? Better to KNOW where its doing things than bypass

Comment: I have stepped through the code and not had any luck.  It does not seem to be a line of code that is executing that causes this.  The master form also uses default datasession.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @EddieC, see revision

Comment: That didn't help.  The alias does get changed when I do SELECT FRT1 in the Init,   It just seems that after it finishes the freight.init() method it goes off and does something in the main form.  I used event tracking and nothing shows up after the init() to indicate it goes back to the main form but it must.  I tried moving the SELECT FRT1 to the Activate() of the form and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: @EddieC, although you did fix it, see revised answer to hopefully SOLVE WHY vs just the bypass your solution allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the program() idea.  It verified that after the init(), program execution goes back to the button that called the form, and because that button is in a grid, I guess it does something strange, even though it does not appear to be any lines of code it runs, And now, it shows events that weren't showing before 
46067.983, freight.Init()
46075.805, zformdis.Paint()
46075.826, zformdis.Paint()
46075.852, freight.Activate()
46075.884, freight.Deactivate()
46075.892, freight.Paint()
46075.898, zformdis.Paint()
46104.013, freight.Paint()
46104.036, freight.Paint()

Answer (score 2):

Aren't there any controls on the called form (typically a grid) that gets the focus and hence implicitly cause a change to current workarea?

BTW, I suggest using private data session and keeping each session separate.